# Sum of rational numbers in (0,1)

Tags: calculus

Just out of curiousity , will the sum of all numbers belongs to rational numbers intercept open interval (0,1) equal to something?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1n$ diverges

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity ,what if 0,1 is not included?

Comment: $\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac1n$ diverges, so, no.

Comment: Alternatively consider the finite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac kn$. This equals $\frac{n-1}2$, and we can always choose a bigger $n$, so the sum is unbounded.

Comment: Or even more simply:  the Archimedean property of the real numbers asserts that if $M$ and $\varepsilon$ are any positive numbers, then there exists a $k$ so large that $k\varepsilon > M$.  In the interval $(\varepsilon,1)$, there are infinitely many rational numbers larger than $\varepsilon$.  By the Archimedean property, we just have to pick out "enough" of them to make the sum large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among the rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ are infinitely many number greater than $1/2.$

Therefore the sum is at least as big as what you get from adding up $1/2$ infinitely many times. So it is $+\infty.$